# Different order sorting on different elements in a list of list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists,

> mylist = [['zzz', 100], ['sss', 100], ['555',100], ['222',100], ['333',90]]

This is a sorted(Descending order) list based on based on using the following function

> sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)

I want to sort this in such a way so I get the following order

> [['222',100], ['555',100], ['sss', 100], ['zzz', 100], ['333',90]]

that is sorted `desc` order on scores x[1], where as `asc` order on values x[0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close and fortunate.

Fortunate because:

You have at-least one numeric value, that you can negate to create a different order

Close because,

thats what you were missing

```
>>> mylist = [['zzz', 100], ['sss', 100], ['555',100], ['222',100], ['333',90]]
>>> sorted(mylist, key = lambda e: (-e[1], e[0]))
[['222', 100], ['555', 100], ['sss', 100], ['zzz', 100], ['333', 90]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy if you need to reverse the order of a numeric field, just negate it

```
>>> mylist = [['zzz', 100], ['sss', 100], ['555',100], ['222',100], ['333',90]]
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))
[['222', 100], ['555', 100], ['sss', 100], ['zzz', 100], ['333', 90]]
```

If you had to sort for example two string fields, one ascending and one descending it's [not quite so easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112082/174728)

Answer (score 3):

In the case that you can't use negation, for example all the elements are string, you can create a compare function, and use `functools.cmp_to_key` to convert it to a key function.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
mylist = [['zzz', 100], ['sss', 100], ['555',100], ['222',100], ['222',90]]
def f(a, b):
    return cmp(a[0], b[0]) or -cmp(a[1], b[1])
sorted(mylist, key=cmp_to_key(f))
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this isn't used in this special case as it causes the key func to be called more times - so it's slower